# QUrl removes colon from c:/path/to/file

Tags: qt, qt5

I want my application to be cross-platform and create a directory inside the users documents folder. I get that from QStandardPaths.
When creating a QUrl from that String it becomes `c/path/to/documents/` instead of the desired `c:/path/to/documents`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating `QUrl` the string before ":" is interpreted as URL protocol. To create one that point to local file, you should use [`fromLocalFile`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromLocalFile) static method:

```
qDebug() << QUrl::fromLocalFile("c:\\path\\to\\documents");
```

This code will print the correct URL starting with file protocol prefix:

```
QUrl("file:///C:/path/to/documents")
```

You also have `isLocalFile` and `toLocalFile` methods.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't able to find this info in the QUrl doc, though maybe I was just looking for the wrong thing.